# headnode of singly Linked list has default value?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
  public:
   int data;
   Node * next;
};

void Append(Node * head, int newdata){
  Node * n = head;
  if(n->next != NULL)
  {
    n = n->next;
  }
  n->data = newdata;
  cout<<"data-> "<<newdata<<" inserted!"<<endl;
}

void Display(Node * head){
  Node * n = head;
  if(n->next != NULL)
  {
    cout<<"data->"<<n->data<<endl;
    n = n->next;
  }
  cout<<"data->"<<n->data<<endl;
}
int main(int argc, char * argcv[])
{
  Node * headnode;
  int newdata = 20;
  Append(headnode, newdata);
  Display(headnode);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
data-> 20 inserted!
data->1
data->20
```

Why the headnode has been assigned a "1" data member here?

Comment: `headnode` is uninitialized and contains random data.

Comment: I'm surprised the program even runs without segfaulting.  The next node never gets initialized either.

Comment: There isn't even a next node. Oh dear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the comments, the problem here is that you are sending a pointer to a Node in your append function without initializing the data and the pointer that it contains.

On the   `if(n->next != NULL)` inside append, `n->next` will also be random data, meaning that you will assign the value 20 not to the "head" but to the node that the head points to.

That is why the value 20 is on the next node when printing, and random value of (in this case 1) is in your head node.

You need to use the `new` in order to allocate the Nodes in the memory, as dereferencing a pointer that isn't pointing to allocated memory will most likely cause segfaults.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the comments and answer by @Milan, I think the design of class `Node` can be better implemented. It's not always required to expose data members( i.e., `Node::data` ) and especially in this case. class `Node` can also have member functions that does appending a new link and display the linked list. To get an idea, think of the way the container **std::list** is implemented( i.e., its member functions ). Take the advantage of powerful feature, *data hiding*, in **C++**.